# Custom Vim Write Function To Make a Backup Copy

Tags: vim, backup

I want to create a write function in Vim that does the following:

- Copies the file before it was edited to a directory (lets call this back_up_before_last_change)
- Writes the new edits to the current file
- Copies the updated file to a directory (lets call this back_up)

This way I could look an older change and if the file gets accidentally deleted I would always have a most recent backup. Would anyone know how to do this or recommend me some resource so I could figure it out for myself. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would *highly* recommend some form of version control, like [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). This will give you the file history that you want (bonus: branching) and will also provide easy way to clone and share history between different repositories.

#### Git

You can use a plugin like [vim-futitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) to handle staging, commits, and many other git functions. [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) provides some a nice [screencast tutorial](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/) for fugitive:

- [A complement to command line git](http://vimcasts.org/e/31)
- [Working with the git index](http://vimcasts.org/e/32)
- [Resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/e/33)
- [Browsing the git object database](http://Browsing%20the%20git%20object%20database)
- [Exploring the history of a git repository](http://vimcasts.org/e/35)

#### Persistent Undo

To go along with version control, Vim also provides persistent undo where it save's Vim's undo history to a file. See `:h persistent-undo`.

Simply set `'undofile'` in your `vimrc`:

```
set undofile
```

May want to set `'undodir'` to a different location, e.g. `set undodir=~/.local/vim/undo`. Note: `'undodir'` must exist.

It should be noted persistent undo is **not** version control and should not be treated as such. For example undo history can easily be messed up by editing a file in a different editor.

Plugins like [Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) and [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) may help in navigating deep in the past or complicated undo histories.

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation for a full version control system; but for some locations, this just isn't feasible. I've implemented the [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) to have a minimal backup scheme within Vim. The companion [writebackupVersionControl plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1829) extends it to work with those backups, and finally the [writebackupAutomator plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3940) allows you to *automatically* trigger backups on each day:

> Wouldn't it be nice if Vim detected
>   that you have made backups of a file in the past, and automatically creates a
>   new backup - without any action on your side?
>
> This plugin builds on the writebackup.vim and
>   writebackupVersionControl.vim plugins, and automatically writes a backup on
>   a day's first write of a file that was backed up in the past, but not yet
>   today.
>   This gives you one no-hassle, worry-free backup every day. For many
>   writebackup.vim use cases (like editing config files distributed all over
>   /etc/), this initial "good state from the past" backup is the most important
>   one. (And of course you can still manually trigger additional checkpoint
>   backups via :WriteBackup as in the past.)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Vim to generate a new backup file each time you write, e.g. with `:w`. A way to do this is recommended right in the `:help` for the `backupext` option.

My version of this is:

```
:au BufWritePre * let &backupext=("." . strftime("%y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S"))
```

If your file is `foo.txt`, it names the backup file like `foo.txt.22-01-04:19:35:42`.

If you do two fast writes within the same second, the name will be the same, so you will lose a version. (Don't have a habit of issuing multiple `:w` commands in quick succession.)

I also set the `backupdir` option to a specific directory which holds all these backups.

That directory is going to accumulate a lot of cruft; you probably want some periodically run script to clean them away if they are more than a few weeks or months old. Unless you're that type of person who has sudden discoveries, like that you uknowingly made a bad edit to a file five years ago, and want the version of that file from five minutes before that.